# MassTransit Publisher no exception thrown

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

I have a MassTransit Producer / Publisher developed in Asp.Net Web API.

The producer simply sends message to the Exchange -> Queue.

```
public async Task<bool> AddToQueue(int msgId, Message message)
{
     var endpoint = await _bus.GetSendEndpoint(new Uri("exchange:testExchange?bind=true&queue=MessageQueue"));
     await endpoint.Send(new Message()
     {
         Id = msgId,
         Text = message.Text
     });
     return true;
}
```

However, the above would not return any exception (even if I had some sort of handling in place) if for instance queue was not found or there was an issue with binding etc. Message will simply get lost with no sign of it creating an error queue?

I understand it will create a queue if one was not found but am sure if there was an issue between with the Message broker and producer how would you handle that?

Comment: [Is this the same issue?](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/issues/1541) Seems to be "as intended"...

Comment: Thanks @MatthewWatson It seems like it. However, I don't understand why this is the case? As producer, there should be some of raised exception?

Comment: The guy that posted it as a bug report would agree with you! :) It seems like a bug to me too...

Answer (score -1):

To get an exception from task operation you need to assign result of your method execution to Task variable, like this:

```
Task<bool> myTask = AddToQueue(42, "Some message");
```

And than you can get your exception from Exception property of Task:

```
if (myTask.Exception != null) 
    Console.WriteLine(myTask.Exception.InnerException.Message);
```

Comment: The use of `await` by the OP would cause the exception to be thrown at that point (if one occured).

Comment: I have also tried the above by assigning it to a task and wait for it to complete, still no exception is raised and message is simply lost.

Comment: This answer is unfortunately completely wrong